# How can NSRegularExpression give me a NSRange out of bounds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsregularexpression

I am using `NSRegularExpression` to find the occurrence of a string on a text. Something like this:

```
  NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                                regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<a href=\"(.*)\">(.*)</a>[:blank:]|[:blank:](.*)\\n\\n\\n"
                                options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                error:&error];
```

Then, I enumerate the results using this:

```
  [regex enumerateMatchesInString:textContent options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [textContent length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){

  }];
```

Inside the block and because the result can have multiple ranges, I have these lines:

```
NSInteger numberOfRanges = [match numberOfRanges];

// then I enumerate the ranges

for (int i=0; i<[match numberOfRanges]; i++) {
  NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:i];
  // The problem here is that some ranges come out of bounds
}
```

The problem is that while enumerating the ranges, some are out of bounds. How can that be if these ranges were found by the code itself???

Comment: It's very hard to say what's going on in the abstract. Can you create a minimal example project, with sample data, that exhibits the problem and post it somewhere like Github?

Comment: Is match nil when you're crashing? in that case, in Objective-C, numberOfRanges will come through as nil, and the for loop will execute once and crash. Seems to me you need an `if (match == nil) { return }` at the top of your block to test for that case.

Comment: @DuncanC - ok, but how can you explain a NSRange equal to nil when numberOfRanges is bigger than 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask yourself what happens when a parenthesised expression in a regular expression matches nothing? For example, consider the RE:

```
(a)|(b)(c)?(d)
```

and the strings it matches:

```
a
bd
bcd
```

Now in the RE there are *always* four parenthesised expressions, so `numberOfRanges` will always be 4 even though it is never possible for all of them to be matching something (due to the or `|`). So what is returned for a range that doesn't match anything? Check the docs for `NSRegularExpression` and you'll find it is the range `{NSNotFound, 0}`, that is the `location` member has the value `NSNotFound`.

It is this "no match" range that is giving you the error as you do not check for it.

HTH

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I thought NSRegularExpression would just consider a match if the 3 conditions were a match but it is not the case.